# Tweaking VBA Autocomment Script

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really new to VBA (decided to try and start learning it in depth yesterday), and so I've set myself a little project.

I found this code (from [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/515724-show-contents-cell-when-hovering-2.html#post2688755)), and am trying to logic my way through it, but I'm stuck - I want to point it at just the currently selected range, not loop it through all the worksheets and all the Used Cells in those worksheets. I keep getting type errors when I try define 'iCell' as the current Selection.

```
Sub CommentTheHeckOuttaIt()
    Dim WS                          As Worksheet
    Dim iCell                       As Range
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each iCell In WS.UsedRange
            With iCell
                If CStr(.Value) <> "" Then
                    .ClearComments
                    .AddComment
                    .Comment.Visible = False
                    .Comment.Text Text:=CStr(.Value)
                    .Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 5.87, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                    .Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 2.26, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                End If
                If .Formula <> "" Then
                    .ClearComments
                    .AddComment
                    .Comment.Visible = False
                    .Comment.Text Text:=CStr(.Formula)
                    .Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 5.87, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                    .Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 2.26, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                End If
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub



Sub AllCommentsMustDIE()
    Dim WS                          As Worksheet
    Dim iCell                       As Range
    For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each iCell In WS.UsedRange
            iCell.ClearComments
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm happy to read if you know of a reference that'd be relevant here, not necessarily looking for someone to solve it for me. I just don't know how to phrase the search.

Comment: Without solving it for you... Hints: `For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` loops through each worksheet, so you could remove that loop. `For Each iCell In WS.UsedRange` loops through all of the cells that have values.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The "For Each iCell In WS.UsedRange" - I gather that it's somehow referring to the parent loop? Sorceri's solution below changed 'WS.UsedRange' to 'Selection' and that makes it work.

Am I correct in my understanding that WS.UsedRange refers to a range (equal to all the used cells on a worksheet), and so does Selection?

Comment: usedrange looks at all the cells that have data and returns a range that represents that

Answer (score 0):

You would need to remove the outer for loop to not do it for all worksheets.  Then you need to loop through the selected range; such as below.  I will let you fix the second sub.

```
Sub CommentTheHeckOuttaIt()
    Dim iCell As Range
    For Each iCell In Selection
        With iCell
            If CStr(.Value) <> "" Then
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment
                .Comment.Visible = False
                .Comment.Text Text:=CStr(.Value)
                .Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 5.87, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                .Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 2.26, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            End If
            If .Formula <> "" Then
                .ClearComments
                .AddComment
                .Comment.Visible = False
                .Comment.Text Text:=CStr(.Formula)
                .Comment.Shape.ScaleWidth 5.87, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
                .Comment.Shape.ScaleHeight 2.26, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool - it was the For Each iCell in "Selection" bit that I was apparently missing. I thought somehow that you needed to 'set' iCell to the current selection.

Comment: So...

Sub AllCommentsMustDIE()
    Dim iCell                       As Range
        For Each iCell In Selection
            iCell.ClearComments
        Next
End Sub

For the second procedure (subroutine?)?

Comment: yup that would do it